# How can forbid direct displaying View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Can the following situation be solved?
-I have a view: **All**.cshtml
-I have a Controller and two action in it (**All**, **FakeAll**)

I want to **forbid** to earn the **All View from** the **FakeAll action** (and other Fakes or anyone).

```
public ActionResult FakeAll()
{
    //There is some setting what ALWAYS have to be runned 
    //before the All view is displayed
    return View("All");
    //It should be throw a design time error or an exception
}

public ActionResult All()
{
    return View("All");
    //It should be display the view without any interception as its do it now.
}
```

The access of All View should be executed through the All Action only.

The MAIN thing is:
Evertime when somebody try to call `return View("All");` then it should be get an error or something

Comment: Why do you need this `FakeAll`? Making it private would be an option?

Comment: If you are using any type of membership you could decorate it with the `[Authorize]` and thus, only authenticated users can access that action.

Comment: I Edited my question for more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "override" the Controller method `View`

```
public ViewResult View(string viewName,
    [CallerMemberName]string memberName = "")
{
    if (viewName != memberName)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid view name");
    }

    return base.View(viewName);
}
```

If the method name calling `View()` is not the same as the viewname it will throw an exception.

Comment: This override will work for every View and conrtoller, or do you point for one specific override?

Comment: You would have to override every overload, I made only one. And for it to work on every controller the best approach I think it would be to create a class `BaseController` and make every controller in your application to inherit from it rather than `Controller`.

Comment: I See, I will try it tomorrow, here is 01:00 and im tired, but the answer looks like good :)

Comment: Do you think it is possible to send a design time error about it?

Comment: It looks like crazy and tasty. But shoot a bird with uranium racket :P

Comment: Finally i solved it with your help. But I put into the real overrider method the lines what is always have to be executed (presettings). And everytime when the All view is displayed, the presettings in the overrided method is executed. Thanks for the points and helps!